# Trying to make a webpage where the contents don't flow over eachother

Tags: html, css, positioning, margin, margins

I want a webpage so in different screen resolutions the webpage contents have a scroll bar on the side instead of overlapping eachother. This is what i have for css

```
 @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    overflow:auto;
    font-weight:light;
    font-family:Andale Mono, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.875em;
    font-weight:lighter;
    text-align:center;
}

a:link {        /* unvisited link */
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}     
a:visited {     /*  visited link  */
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
} 
a:hover {       /* mouse over link */
    color:#C60;
    text-decoration:none;
}  

div.mainbody {
    margin-top:3%;
    font-size:1em;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}

div.textbody {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:.875em;
    margin-top:1%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
}

div.arrowleft {
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    margin-left:25%;
}

div.arrowright {
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    margin-right:30%;
    margin-left:70%;
}

div.Footerbar {
    background:#ffffff;
    border-style:dashed;
    border-width:1px;
    border-left-style:none;
    border-right-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:1%;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    padding-bottom:;
    padding-top:;
    font-size:.70em;
    font-weight:lighter;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:.2em;
}

div.footer {
    z-index:2;
    background:#ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    font-size:9px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:2px; 
}

div.ads {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:4%;
    width:728px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and when i put one of my pages in a standard monitor resolution (1024x768) It causes items to overlap instead of making a search bar. Please help meeee

Answer (score 0):

Not much details given in your question. Here's an example i did where divs do not overlap.  As you expand the window contents will start floating horizontally next each other, when window size is smaller, they dropdown vertically. **Check example http://jsfiddle.net/5zcge/**